# How to add only values of list without brackets in python string formatting

Tags: python

In the code below, how can I remove the brackets in the output?

```py
In [11]: xx = [1,2,3,4]

In [12]: print('%s BLAH' %xx)
[1, 2, 3, 4] BLAH
```

I would like the output to be:

```
1, 2, 3, 4 BLAH
```

I am looking for a general solution, NOT something like below (I want to use `%s` only once):

```
print('%s %s %s %s BLAH' %tuple(xx))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join the list to a string:

```py
print('%s BLAH' % ', '.join(xx))
```

Comment: Thanks! (I realized that the `xx` has to be converted to list first for your solution to work)

Answer (score 1):

Straightforward way would be to use [join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

```
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> ', '.join([str(x) for x in a])
'1, 2, 3, 4'
>>>
```

If you want to not use join then override the str dunder function of the list class. Please see below:

```
class FancyList(list):
    def __repr__(self):
        fancy_output = ''
        for item in self:
            fancy_output += f'{item}, '
        return fancy_output.strip().strip(',')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__repr__()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = [1,2,3,4]
    print(a)
    fancy_a = FancyList(a)
    print(fancy_a)
    print('%s BLAH' % fancy_a)
    fancy_a.append(100)
    print(fancy_a)
    print('%s BLAH' % fancy_a)
```

which gives me output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
1, 2, 3, 4
1, 2, 3, 4 BLAH
1, 2, 3, 4, 100
1, 2, 3, 4, 100 BLAH
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually can do it without %s with this code:

```
print(', '.join(xx) + " BLAH")
```